# EclipseLink JPA inheritance without discriminator column

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, discriminator

I have a Client and Affiliate class, inheriting from Person class. Joined inheritance strategy type is being used - each of them sharing primary key with the parent class. As there's no discriminator column we chose to use [DescriptorCustomizer and ClassExtractor](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Inheritance#.40ClassExtractor). But it doesn't really give any idea how it works, also, the code doesnt seem to compile. It would be nice if someone gives a nice example with code snippet for understanding.

Comment: _"the code doesnt seem to compile"_ Wouldn't be better to paste your code so that we can take a look on it and try to find the root cause?

Comment: @wypierprz The code given in the EclipseLink website doesn't compile. In `AirMilesExtractor`, the `extractorClassFromRow()` has `void` return type and even then it's returning `Class`. Also, it's not clear what it's trying to achieve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [mentioned documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Inheritance#.40ClassExtractor):

> If you are mapping to an existing database, and the tables do not have
>   a discriminator column you can still define inheritance using the
>   `@ClassExtractor` annotation or `<class-extractor>` element. The class
>   extractor takes a class that implements the `ClassExtractor`
>   interface. An instance of this class is used to determine the class
>   type to use for a database row. The class extractor must define a
>   `extractClassFromRow()` method that takes the database `Record` and
>   `Session`.

we need to annotate the root entity in a hierarchy with user defined using the class extractor:

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@ClassExtractor(PersonClassExtractor.class)
public abstract class Person {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    // ...
}
```

Notice that we don't use `@Customizer` annotations since as this is not required in case of `JOINED` inheritance strategy:

> If a class extractor is used with `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance, the rows
>   of the class type must be able to be filtered in queries. This can be
>   accomplished by setting an `onlyInstancesExpression()` or
>   `withAllSubclassesExpression()` for branch classes. These can be set
>   to `Expression` objects using a `DescriptorCustomizer`.

The class extractor must be able to determine and return the class type from the database row.
In general we need a replacement of a discriminator column, i.e.

- column name unique for a given entity type among others
- criteria based on values of a given column of the root entity

Suppose that each of inherited entity type in a hierarchy has a column with unique name:

```java
@Entity
public class Client extends Person {
    @Column(name = "CLIENT_SPECIFIC")
    private String clientSpecific;
    // ...
}

@Entity
public class Affiliate extends Person {
    @Column(name = "AFFILIATE_SPECIFIC")
    private float affiliateSpecific;
    // ...
}
```

then class extractor may look as follows:

```java
public class PersonClassExtractor extends ClassExtractor {
    @Override
    public Class<?> extractClassFromRow(Record databaseRow, Session session) {
        if (databaseRow.containsKey("CLIENT_SPECIFIC")) {
            return Client.class;
        } else if (databaseRow.containsKey("AFFILIATE_SPECIFIC")) {
            return Affiliate.class;
        } else {
            return Person.class; // this should never happen
        }
    }
}
```

---

- retrieve a list of clients and affiliates

```java
List<Person> polymorphicResults = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p")
                                    .getResultList();
```

- retrieve a list of affiliates or clients respectively

```java
List<Affiliate> concreteResults = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Affiliate a")
                                    .getResultList();

List<Client> concreteResults = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Client c")
                                 .getResultList();
```