# Can I use existing column as DiscriminatorColumn?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm looking at example of DiscriminatorColumn at EclipseLink page.

There are two entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PROJECT")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING,length=20)
@DiscriminatorValue("P")
public class Project {

    @Id
    protected BigInteger id;
    protected String description;

}
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("L")
public class LargeProject extends Project {

    protected BigInteger budget;

}
```

now lets say i have two records in my db

```
| ID | TYPE |  DESCRIPTION  |  BUDGET |
|-----------|---------------|---------|
| 1  |  P   | Small Project |         |
| 2  |  L   | Large Project |  10000  |
```

Is it possible to drop `TYPE` table somehow, and use `BUDGET` table instead? 
For this case would be `Project` if `BUDGET` is `null` otherwise it will be `LargeProject`

Can JPA or EclipseLink allow to do something like that, and if not, is it any reason for that?

Comment: I doubt it, what if you change the budget of a small project so that it surpasses the threshold and becomes a large project, should it then magically change type?

Comment: @Tobb yes, i threshold change type change as well (or if provided mapping dont allow to do that, everything blows up and throws exception)

Comment: The answer here is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22430894/496099